# gcc 9.3.0 printf %Lf output not correct

Tags: gcc, floating-point, printf, precision, long-double

`printf("%Lf", long double)` truncates the output to `double`. Or, am I doing something wrong?

Gcc 9.3.0 Ubuntu 20.04.2, Linux 5.8.0-59-generic

```
printf("print m_pi  %.45f\n", M_PI);
printf("print m_pil %.45LF\n", M_PIl);
printf("maple Pi    3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197\n");
printf("m_pil def   3.141592653589793238462643383279502884L\n");
```

Output:

```
print m_pi  3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576172
print m_pil 3.141592653589793238512808959406186204432742670
maple Pi    3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
m_pil def   3.141592653589793238462643383279502884L
```

It seems like gcc `printf` is truncating `long double` to 13 digits +-.

Comment: how is `M_PIl` defined?

Comment: In math.h, which is included from cmath.
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884L

Comment: Look at 'man printf', f and F are the same except F is uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

> `printf("%Lf", long double)` truncates the output to double

It clearly doesn't truncate anything. It's easy to see the result for `double` and `long double` are completely different and `long double` are more precise than `double`

So there's nothing wrong with it. On x86 `long double` is typically [80-bit extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) type whose precision is [around 18 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log10%282%5E64%29), and `3.141592653589793238` is correct to 19 significant digits

If you need some more precision then use [quadruple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) by setting the [`-mlong-double-128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) option or use [`__float128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) directly. Of course this is emulated by software so it'll be significantly slower than the native x87 80-bit format

[Demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:22,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:22,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:22,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:22),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Climits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cquadmath.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++char+M_PI128%5B128%5D+%3D+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++quadmath_snprintf(M_PI128,+sizeof+M_PI128,+%22%25.45Qf%22,%0A++++++++3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197q)%3B%0A%0A++++printf(%22print+m_pi++++%25.45f%5Cn%22,+M_PI)%3B%0A++++printf(%22print+m_pil+++%25.45Lf%5Cn%22,+M_PIl)%3B%0A++++printf(%22print+m_pi128+%25s%5Cn%22,+M_PI128)%3B%0A++++printf(%22maple+Pi++++++3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++printf(%22m_pil+def+++++3.141592653589793238462643383279502884L%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22long+double+precision:+%22+%3C%3C%0A++++++++std::numeric_limits%3Clong+double%3E::digits10+%3C%3C+%22+digits%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.95077149155033,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-fext-numeric-literals+-O2+-lquadmath%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.331155972278154,l:%274%27,m:53.59019264448336,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40980735551664,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.049228508449666,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

For higher precisions you'll have to use a 3<sup>rd</sup> party arbitrary-precision floating-point library

---

> Why is `size(long double)` 16 bytes?

Size has nothing to do with precision. Just like trap representations and padding bits are allowed in C++, a type's size can be wider than the real precision

In the 80-bit extended format the internal representation is 10 bytes but padding bytes are added to align the type to 4 bytes (x86) or 8 bytes (x86-64), resulting in a 16-byte type in 64-bit mode. The padding can be changed by the [`-m96/128bit-long-double`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) options in gcc

What's important here is `LDBL_DIG`/`LDBL_MANT_DIG`/`LDBL_MAX_EXP`/`LDBL_MAX_10_EXP` or `std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits/digits10/max_exponent/max_exponent10`which are the real precision of the type. In fact by changing the combinations of the above `-m-long-double` options you'll get many different results:

- [`-mlong-double-128`](https://tio.run/##pY/LCsIwEEX3/YqhbixYsK4k1n5JQWKaloE8xKQbxV83NilWkSrSzirM3HvCYadT2jDmFqiYaCsOOWpjz5zKInrtBEq0pnCoLEiKaplE1wi6MbYihOnWQp5DXAtNLSltaQ1eOOwh9mv/1vUyHJPQ8uPzK6iw6cDZesh6nmolPyM79L/moVgQ8syOIjb/E0KvVPFuxKDS7VHwbwr9dYpD35wl8YH4ZSG0amBQGRF5C0yxeavPUhrjvLxuzt1ZLWhjXCp9NO2jabbZPgA): size = 16, digits10 = 33, digits2 = 113
- [`-m96bit-long-double`](https://tio.run/##pY/bCoJAEIbvfYrBbgwSqougzXwSIXRdZWAP4o43Ra/e5iodCIuouVpm/u9fPt40cc25m6HmsisFJGgstSJXafDYSVRINnWoCVSOOpoHpwD6sVQyxk1HkCQQVtLkxDLKyOJRwB5Cv/ZvU0XDcT5Qfnx@ASXWffFqec/6Pt0p0SI/jL8mA5gydstOVqy/bxi4TIe7CYPSdIUU7xTG6y8OI/mXxEvFJwtpdA13lQmRp8AvNk/4X0pTPQ@vs3MXXsm8ti5W202BFHsgHoEr): size = 12, digits10 = 18, digits2 = 64
- [`-mlong-double-64`](https://tio.run/##pY/dCoJAEEbvfYrBbhQSKqKLzXwSIWxdZWB/xF1vil69zVVSCYuwuVpmvu8sh1ZVVFJqVygpb3IGMSptapaJxBt3HAUanViUBkSGMgi9mwftaJMTQlVjII7BL7jKDElNajReGZzAd2v3VkXQHcOu5cbl15Bj2YK3myHreLIRrEZ67n@Nu2JCyCs7i9j9Tuh6qfSPMwa5ai6cfVLor0sc@uZfEm@IbxZcyRIGlRmRSWCJzaT@l9IcZ/S6W/ugBc9KbSPholEfjQ77Jw): size = 8, digits10 = 15, digits2 = 53

The default result is size = 16, digits10 = 18, digits2 = 64. You'll get size = 10 if you disable padding, but that'll come at a performance expense due to misalignment. See more demo on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLgDZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxdOdyUVMNoGAmZiAgDjU05FZUxVPxS0ggi7R2c3RVT0zKCchWqS6zLoiriASkVUA2JkDgByKQBma2RDLABqcSGddQbiTGYjaexxAAYAQWHR8cwpmdY8I0IFFfWtzesCCaNmawh28/EAdllNiY%2BJhvQQFG7r6Y6QFTSSSKisVDMAggcQAVh0BDhCJ8AC89tMACIgyT7IEzL54NGoKjUCFQx7vT5UwHAqSSUgTfDAE6cNb7LF03HA76/WjGZx4ZAAfUOxwIpxm4MhiKG2F%2BTJZa3OVOpM1poIZCvFOMx2K5%2BJ5ID5RgFwtFJ0BUqhK3leGZ4v1OmxSNodOmbw2VMNaAMALV%2BLp6G6DnYMPhiPDqPRQw5oMdBKJJKDBhDmApnpVHxpAY1jLtivZeuzTsNxtNIqOFpmydTNpAWoUrOVmfjdM1%2Be1hc5xa%2BBB%2BRv5xEFFbFEp0NfYdYbrdBLrdQw9Xr7vx9frxTrpENEjODoaR4sJ0djOv9JcPxIgW%2BAO5T7HTLZn9Lz9sbbN13dPvf7ZaHZsr4sBK8b1rWVbRfJtKUzHs22fE4T2PeNS0HYdzQAg46GvCdMCnDsFEfOdZwXJ5ngxc5%2Bk6VgQH6WF%2BlIUx%2BjWWjUCooEZDkL5ul6dFJCGThaOhBjyM6ABrEAeIAOlcbhuFcZ5XFcAAOTgAE41meSRYSEKjuFo%2BjGNIZj%2BlohQQDWUgBMYzo4FgGBED%2BIwPDwdgyAoCA0AcpyKmAZT6SoJyCGcEyIAcKj9Icaw0gATyovjSHck16AAeVoVhosE0gsFuURQ3S/AFgKAA3TATPSzAAA98l9AZ9KuZRQtow4HGIKK9CwGL%2BKHIx2s6Gh6CYNgOB4fhBGEUQUDkOQhDwBwTMgTpUA8JISoAWkSnFlqMK9lqw5bOEkBTjLyAoNAgcxamyUhzFKKIYmCbxfDoc67tCPxrvKWJckSQpGie%2BojqSIp0je1oPoaYpfqqYpgduzhOgUTi%2Bi4CiqJouj6oMqiyoU1xlqkiZgGQZAJmU8ScQgXBCBIEFeIZPQPOc6nYYmVjZBkfj6qspB3Mc5zyEobnPJcbzfP8wLKBC9LwtoKL2ri1AjASghktS9HMpEYAcv0vL8jUIqSv08rKoC9Haso9LGua4hItagZYoITrutIXrGBYUMhoEelRrECaZCmmb4Hmxa/BWtaJg25TXHCghlq2rDDq%2Bk6zv0LIzG0aG2k8e6kghkIHtodPQf%2B77weTupPp14ugeaG6M7BmpS4uuumkid6ka6HpEdhrTqN09HDKxnG8YJomSbJimiGIRnaflnnnGpyR2mZn3pHZwTOfs2eXP5mfBZAYWndF4ggolsKIqt2X4q0JWUrSrXMCyjXqto7XCuK9HDeQKqTfoOrzemy3rYYFth1I4jtnb9TdrwAQQwhDq3GmxX2jVZoPAMkHOgId1qbQwttXcmBcY6XLsdUwp1tAQyutXVuORc7Zwbs9POBdBAJArnQQGGRaF/QTskRoDD6g/XYZDKuLcQZt3hh3QayMe5o3Sv3bG%2BD8aE2JqTCY5N8ATynszHeDNhhDEXizOQq9LIiRAK4NY4k9rcFZJwBSykLHYyUt3AhXVYRmT0kxKixkxLmQ5qQaydl/geF9HzNymiM6YFUSQQQ4DXaDV4AAd2ah4R2ZtUauIxoMHinAJixMIAgCYA85HD0UZIAx5EfFIH8YE1yAtnKeLCZTD6USBpcDiQkpJKNe7SKosMHE2SCC5PyUPBRo8SnrwqQQIJ1SKgwLqRPSJdAXZNKGvE5giT%2Bh8QkSkvuXSeJDCyTkvJsjBkj1JiMzoCBFhYBcCgs2jiQDOKkfpQyHizIWSEqQUSclxJDFhLCIYOyrFrB8s8XgZshgdMee4rxa8JHFIeW4oyULDGkCKkfPwIBuBAA)

See

- [Size of long double on Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21968474/995714)
- [Why does a long double take up only 10 bytes in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67045315/995714)
- [sizeof long double and precision not matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17382879/995714)

In PowerPC you can also see [the same phenomena when changing the floating-point format](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Climits%3E%0A%0Aint+get(int+%26size,+int%26+digits2)%0A%7B%0A++++size+%3D+sizeof(long+double)%3B%0A++++digits2+%3D+std::numeric_limits%3Clong+double%3E::digits%3B%0A++++return+std::numeric_limits%3Clong+double%3E::digits10%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:34.81384715871979,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppc64g8,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27power64+AT12.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppc64g8,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-mabi%3Dieeelongdouble%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27power64+AT12.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:65.1861528412802,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). While the size is still 16 bytes, the precision can vary. With `-mabi=ibmlongdouble` ([double-double arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic), which is the default) you'll get (size, digits10, digits2) = (16, 31, 106) but with `-mabi=ieeelongdouble` the tuple will become (16, 33, 113)

Comment: Why is size(long double) 16 bytes?

Comment: if my answer helps please click the green check mark to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)